# Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

como puedo realizar la siguiente operacion

```
declare @fecha datetime = '14/01/2019 12:00:00 a. m.'
update factura
set fecha_aprobado = @fecha
where id_factura = 7000079
```

que instruccion puedo indicar para que sea aceptada

Nota: El campo `fecha_aprobado` es de tipo datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar la funcion convert de sql server
para convertir la cadena a datetime

aqui un ejemplo:

```
declare @fecha datetime=CONVERT(datetime,'14/01/2019 12:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar el siguiente formato ya que no necesitaras ejecutar ninguna transformacion extra

'AnoMesDia Hora:Minuto:Segundo.Milisegundos'

es decir

```
declare @fecha datetime = '20190114 00:00:00.000'
update factura
set fecha_aprobado = @fecha
where id_factura = 7000079
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, el valor @fecha lo obtengo de una funcionalidad en c#, lo especifique de esa manera para darme a entender. El formato no lo defino manual

Comment: ese C# genera un script? o el update lo ejecuta el codigo C#?, si es la primer opcion puedes editar el C# para obtener ese formato, si es la segunda opcion el C# manda directo como tipo fecha a la base de datos no se necesita pasar a texto

Comment: el update lo ejecuta el codigo C#, es asi como lo estoy haciendo `DateTime fecha2 = DateTime.Now;` pero tira error

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta opcion:

```
select convert(datetime, campo_fecha,103) from tb_tabla
```

Para ponerlo en una variable como tu indicas puedes hacer esto:

```
DECLARE @fecha datetime=CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),103)
```

puedes usar varios formatos de fecha.

[Puedes consultar este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)